# Can a salesforce custom button have some javascript in it?

Tags: salesforce

What is the current way to do a custom button with some js in it?

We are building a custom button that needs to be able to read from the current contact (email address, phone, mailing address), and run a few lines of js. (We also need to create a call record.)

But how/where is this done in salesforce these days?

This page doesn't point me anywhere:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_enterprise.htm

And this explanation of the new method in Lightning isn't clear where the js lives:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BWr4IAG

Where is the needed example/doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using buttons on custom visualforce page there are no any problems with defining custom JS function for it. For example, if you use `<apex:commandButton/>` you can use such attributes as onclick, onkeydown, onkeyup and other. See more information in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm).

If you are using buttons on object layouts, you can create custom button and chose executing of JS as a behavior, see attached screenshot.[image]

If you mean some other cases, please, describe it.